# Cannot read property 'push' of undefined multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to solve this problem: Write a function that splits an array (first argument) into groups the length of size (second argument) and returns them as a multidimensional array. For example:

```
chunk(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 2)
```

should return

```
[['a'. 'b'], ['c', 'd']]
```

My code is as follows:

```
function chunk(arr, size) {
  var newArr = [[]];
  for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for(j = 0; j < size; j++) {
      newArr[i].push(arr[i + j]);
    }
  }
  return newArr;
}
```

It gives an error: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined. Why is this happening and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this with nested loops, but why not go for a simpler approach and use `array.slice()`?

```
function chunk( input, size ) {
    var output = [];
    for( i = 0;  i < input.length;  i += size ) {
        output.push( input.slice( i, i + size ) );
    }
    return output;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

After

```
for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
```

you must initialize the one-dimensional array:

```
newArr[i] = [];
```

This will solve the error, but not produce the result you want. I think you need something like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < ceil(arr.length / size); i++) {
    newArr[i] = [];
    for (j = 0; j < size; j++) {
        if (i * size + j >= arr.length)
            break;
        newArr[i].push(arr[i * size + j]);
    }
}
```

Comment: can someone explain why there's a break on line 5?

Comment: Suppose `size` = 3, but the original `arr` has 7 members. The last 'chunk' will contain only 1 element - after that, there will be no more members to fill the remaining 2 spots in the last chunk. This is where the `break` comes in.